# Any idea how to "not" count the keywords in the set if it is in a comment or string?

Tags: java

I need to make this program count the keywords in .java source code files(which it does), but it also needs to disgregard the keywords that are in any comments or in strings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.!!!

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class CountKeywords {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a Java source file: ");
String filename = input.nextLine();

File file = new File(filename);
if (file.exists()) {
  System.out.println("The number of keywords in " + filename
    + " is " + countKeywords(file));
}
else {
  System.out.println("File " + filename + " does not exist");
}
}

public static int countKeywords(File file) throws Exception {

// Array of all Java keywords + true, false and null

String[] keywordString = {"abstract", "assert", "boolean",
    "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const",
    "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum",
    "extends", "for", "final", "finally", "float", "goto",
    "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int",
    "interface", "long", "native", "new", "package", "private",
    "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static",
    "strictfp", "super", "switch", "synchronized", "this",
    "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile",
    "while", "true", "false", "null"};

Set<String> keywordSet =
  new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(keywordString));
int count = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

while (input.hasNext()) {
  String word = input.next();
  if (keywordSet.contains(word))
    count++;
}

return count;
}
}
```

Comment: Try a flag that looks for `//` and doesn't read the rest of the line. Also one for `/*` that stops counting until `*/`.

Comment: user2208495: Sorry, I didn't read carefully. I've already deleted my comment.

Comment: This gets irritating very quickly. Bottom line is that you should use a state machine. The other option is to make a really small state machine that pays attention to comments *and* string literals.

Comment: In the general case there's really no way around actually parsing the source, I'm afraid.  It doesn't have to be a full parse, but it does get non-trivial pretty quickly.

Comment: This seems like homework. Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Don't re-invent the wheel.  Try one of the many java code parsers out there.  Like https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/

Otherwise you need to implement a whole parser.

**Why?**

Unless you understand the parsing you will miss something.  For example, lets look at this algorithm and see if it works.

1. Ignore all code between " and ".
2. Ignore all code between /* and */
3. Ignore all code on a line after //

Seems easy?  Then you run into "hello \"world".
Ok ok.  we'll account for escaped strings.

Change 1 to Ignore all code between " and ", but ignore \" inside the string.

Okay, that could work... until "hello \\"; private String.....
Well, we just need to account for.....

This is what happens when you roll your own parsers.  You usually do it through trial and error instead of looking at the whole parsing syntax and doing it correctly.  Use a parser from someone that has read the WHOLE BNF for the language and has constructed a well tested parser.  It will save you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use the `skip()` method after every token to tell it to skip comments and strings. A possible pattern is:

`(/\*.*\*/)|(//.*?\n)|("([^"]|\\")*")`

You will have to make sure to properly escape backslashes and quotes when you turn it into a string to pass to `Pattern`.

Note that this still won't parse all Java properly because you most likely didn't take into account that you can have tokens without spaces between them (`true|false`) or Unicode escape codes (`\u002a\u002f`).